# Replacement for cryptography package in python

Tags: python, cryptography

I need to encrypt a little piece of string, nothing very complex, just as so as it gets unintelligible to human eyes, but as I am using my company's notebook to do this I don't have the cryptography package installed nor can I install it.

Is there any replacement for this matter?

PS: I am using python 3.7

Comment: hashlib is included in the Python standard libraries. Does that meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*just as so as it gets unintelligible to human eyes*

Then you might use `rot_13` from built-in module `codecs`. Consider following simple example:

```
import codecs
plain = "Hello World"
cipher = codecs.encode(plain, "rot_13")
print(cipher)  # Uryyb Jbeyq
againplain = codecs.decode(cipher, "rot_13")
print(againplain)  # Hello World
```

*(tested in python 3.7.3)*

Comment: i did not know about this package, thanks a lot it does the job!!